# Compare rows on col A & C in sheet1 with col B & D in sheet2

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010

Hey i am helping a friend, i got a Excel doc with two sheets. On sheet1 there are col A with a firstname and col C with lastname i need to compare those two values with columns B & D in sheet2. If the values match i want the background to turn red.

Example: if A1 = John and C2 = Doe then if there is a John Doe in col B & D in sheet2 i want the background in both sheets to turn red.

Comment: Create a Helper column on both sheets which has a formula (eg) `=A2 & "|" & C2` to concatenate first and last name.  Then you can use MATCH() and conditional formatting.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, I think this is what you want.

```
Sub checked()
    Dim mycell As Range
    Dim mydiff As Integer
    Dim shtSheet1 As Worksheet
    Dim shtSheet2 As Worksheet
    Set shtSheet1 = Worksheets("Compare Sheet1")
    Set shtSheet2 = Worksheets("Compare Sheet2")
    For Each mycell1 In shtSheet1.Range("A2:A4,C2:C4")
        For Each mycell2 In shtSheet2.Range("B2:B4,D2:D4")
          If mycell2.Value = shtSheet1.Cells(mycell1.Row, mycell1.Column).Value Then
            mycell2.Interior.Color = vbRed
            mydiffs = mydiffs + 1
          End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Before:

[image]

[image]

After:

[image]

Obviously, you can modify the code to suit your specific needs if I missed something.